# Full background color for chart.js version 2

Tags: charts

I need to get the result in the answer given in this post [How to set a full length background color for each bar in chartjs bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791034/how-to-set-a-full-length-background-color-for-each-bar-in-chartjs-bar) but with version 2. Basically it is to fill up the full length of the bar with a background color. Any ideas? Thanks in advance